# Tracking global variables with the same name as local variables in C

Tags: c, scope, global-variables

I'm having a few issues tracking the values of global variables when there are local variables that exist with the same name.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int);

int x=6, y=7, z=10;

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int z=5;
    printf("main: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z);
    func(x);
    printf("main: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z);
    func(y);
    printf("main: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z);
    func(z);
    printf("main: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
    }

void
func(int x) {
    x = x+1;
    y = y+1;
    printf("func: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z);
}
```

Note the globals have the same name as the locals in func(), except for z. When I run the program. I get the following output:

```
main: x= 6, y= 7, z= 5
func: x= 7, y= 8, z=10
main: x= 6, y= 8, z= 5
func: x= 9, y= 9, z=10
main: x= 6, y= 9, z= 5
func: x= 6, y=10, z=10
main: x= 6, y=10, z= 5
```

I can understand where the first line comes from. It's just the values of the global variables, but main is using 5 rather than 10 because the global variable shadows the local variable. I can also understand line 2. global variable x is passed into func, giving a 7. Global variable y is used also, giving an 8.

Line 3 is where I lose track of values. Why has the value of global variable y stayed as 8? Did the func() function call change its value permanently? I thought this was not possible since y in func() is just a local variable. I understand where the x = 6 comes from in line 3 though.

Line 4 I lose track even more. How can the value of x jump from 6 to 9?

It would be great if someone could walk me through this output, and perhaps give me a quick explanation on scope and also on shadowing.

Comment: You never declare `y` in `func`, so nothing is shadowed. `func(x)` in `main` doesn't shadow the global `x` either.

Comment: If you really want to boggle your mind, add  `printf("main: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z);` before declaring `int z = 5;` in `main()` (assuming C99 or later support), and add: `{ int z = 20; printf("main: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z); }` too, after one of the other `printf()` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` is not a local variable inside `func()`. In order for it to be a local variable (which would shadow the global `y` variable), you would have to declare another `y` variable inside `func()`, e.g. as in the example below. (This version will always print "y=1", and will not modify the global `y` variable.)

```
void
func(int x) {
    int y = 0;

    x = x+1;
    y = y+1;
    printf("func: x=%2d, y=%2d, z=%2d\n", x, y, z);
}
```

Since `y` is not a local variable inside the original `func()`, it's incrementing the global `y`.

Note that `x` is local to `func()` too, and is passed in by value. That is, a call `func(foo)` will copy the value of `foo` into the `x` parameter, and changing the `x` parameter inside `func()` will *not* change `foo`.

Line 4 comes from the `func(y)` call. It will set the (local) `x` parameter inside `func()` to the current value of the global variable `y`. `y` happens to have the value 8 at that point. (It was incremented from 7 to 8 by the previous call to `func()`.) The assignment `x = x+1` inside `func()` bumps that to 9, which is then printed.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question

> Why has the value of global variable y stayed as 8? Did the func() function call change its value permanently?

Yes it did change the global variable `y` permanently, because it is global and not local (it would be local if it was declared as `int y;`)

> How can the value of x jump from 6 to 9?

You pass the global variable `y`, which is changed to 8 in the first function call, to the function. This value is locally stored in the function as `x`. So x + 1 will become 9.

This is the danger of global variables. Once you name local variables the same you WILL lose track of what value is contains what value.

A little example to explain some details:

```
int x = 3;

int main(){
    int x = 8;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

This will print `8` because the code will grab the local value of `x`.

Furthermore, when you change a global variable this will be remembered for the lifetime of the program.